# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stack'

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I was trying to **scrape** data from a website and I have already installed scrapy. When I was trying to run the below code it was showing "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stack'. Can anyone please tell me what's going on and how can I run the code without having any error?

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from stack.items import StackItem


class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        questions = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="summary"]/h3')

        for question in questions:
            item = StackItem()
            item['title'] = question.xpath(
                'a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['url'] = question.xpath(
                'a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/@href').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code next:

```
item = StackItem()
item['title'] = question.xpath(
    'a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/text()').extract()[0]
item['url'] = question.xpath(
    'a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/@href').extract()[0]
```

I think most possible `stack.items` is something not from `pypi`, it comes from some local code which you copy from, because looks it has strong relationship with `"http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest"`'s html elements.

So, maybe you set up your project as `scrapy startproject stack`, and also need to have a `items.py` like next:

**items.py:**

```
from scrapy import Item, Field

class StackItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    url = Field()
```

Check your referenced document carefully to confirm if any missded.